# Trophies for tennis coaches

Tags: tennis, awards, atp, coaching, wta

Is there an ATP/WTA or grand slam tournament where coaches win a trophy too when their player win the tournament?

Comment: Not tournaments, but check these out: [For the US](https://www.uspta.com/USPTA/About_Us/USPTA_History/National_Awards_Program/USPTA/About_USPTA/History/National_Awards_Program.aspx), [For Canada](https://www.tenniscanada.com/awards/)